# Can you use SELECT * and set condition across all columns

Tags: sql

I have a data table with about 30 columns 1 column is a user id and the rest of them are "items" with the values of ranking from 0 - 29 which indicates an the amount of interest in the item. 0 = No interest 1 = Most and 29 = Least.

Is there away to output all columns with a count without having to write a statement or for each item leveraging the "*" such as

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table t
WHERE * != 0
```

The output would be

```
Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5
xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx
```

xxxxx being the total count of records within the column where value is not 0?

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: The solution is to redesign your database. Having repeating columns is generally a bad idea, precisely because you'll frequently want to query across some or all of them. Instead, unpivot the data, and store one *row*  for each item, `(user id, item #, rank)`. Once you adopt a decent data model, *querying* the data becomes straightforward.

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?  There may be some specific chicanery that would help you.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2005.

My issue it is on the Salesforce platform, there are limitations as to how to build things and running queries requires building the output tables. I am not a SQL expert and trying to find some optimal ways of writing some queries that doesn't require having to work with 30 column names.

Comment: Would a result in one column instead of one row do (i.e. in `Item, Count` pairs)?

Answer (score 0):

You could go through the INFORMATION_SCHEMA and build a query and run it with the sql function EXEC().

Join together INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES with INFROMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. Also just encase you want to reuse it place a variable with the wanted table name. You'll have to filter INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS by the type column you need (int)

Answer (score 0):

There is an XML trick to dynamically normalize data without explicit columns enumeration:

```
With SampleTab (UserId, Item1, Item2) As (
         Select 'A'   , 0    , 1      Union All
         Select 'B'   , 2    , 0      Union All
         Select 'C'   , 3    , 0
), SampleXML As (
    Select CAST((Select * From SampleTab root For XML Auto) AS XML) As Doc
), SampleNormalised As (
    Select
        NodeName = C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
        NodeValue = C.value('(.)[1]', 'int') 
    From SampleXML
    Cross Apply Doc.nodes('/root/@*') AS T(C)
)
    Select NodeName As Item, Count(*) As CountNot0
    From SampleNormalised
    Where NodeName <> 'UserId' AND NodeValue <> 0
    Group By NodeName;
```

Result:

```
Item   CountNot0
-----  ---------
Item1          2
Item2          1
```

Not sure that will help you, but there is no way in SQL to skip one column (`User Id`) in the result set without enumerating all the other columns apart from Dynamic SQL mentioned by [Monofuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37619153/5690722) anyway.